# How to automatically re-indent a YAML file?

Tags: yaml

Let's consider this example:

```
---
foo:
  alice: female
  bob:   male
bar:
  - node: 42
    name: none
  - node: 43
    name: none
```

If I decide to reindent everything and start from this:

```
---
foo:
alice: female
bob:   male
bar:
- node: 42
name: none
- node: 43
name: none
```

I don't have enough information to do it. Actually vim's attempt is this:

```
---
foo:
    alice: female
bob:   male
bar:
    - node: 42
name: none
- node: 43
name: none
```

Ansible cannot make it as well:

```
---
foo:

alice: female
bob:   male
bar:

- node: 42
  name: none
  - node: 43
    name: none
```

I think a possible workaround would be to add a blank line when indentation is increased:

```
---
foo:

  alice: female
  bob:   male
bar:

  - node: 42
    name: none
  - node: 43
    name: none
```

In my opinion, the main problem with YAML is that people are still fighting with tabs, spaces and indent size. For large YAML files that are edited by several people, the resulting file cannot be properly parsed anymore. The two solutions I see are:

1. Use only tabs and force tabs identation as this is the case with Makefiles
2. The above solution

Comment: Changing indentation can be easily performed using replacement with regular expressions, many editors support that. If you firstly drop indentation, you just lose information. Of cource, you cannot restore initial meaning of the YAML file after that.

Comment: +1 for using a good IDE. Having consistent standards (i.e. 2 spaces or 4, actual space characters or tabs) is also necessary when using whitespace delimited systems like YAML and Coffeescript. The issues you describe are just one the reasons why I still prefer JSON or JavaScript

Comment: @PhillipHolmes Your comment is pertinent. I guess the real question behind all of this is: what to choose, JSON, INI or YAML?

Comment: If writing my own system? something with structure based on delimiters (i.e. JSON) - the barrier to entry may be higher, but the overall benefit for multiple people working on the same code is a far better situation than catering for a team of 'one'. I don't believe people that can't handle a small amount of complexity should be that involved in the complex tasks as DevOps requires (you mentioned Ansible which is why I saw this post in the first place ;) ). That said, Ansible uses YAML, so YAML is used and teams greater than 1 need to work the same way regardless of personal preference...

Comment: Using only tabs is problematic because different people have their editor tab indent amount set differently. Usually the solution is to only use spaces and warn on finding tabs. You can still have your editor respond to pressing the TAB key, just make it insert spaces instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you seem to want to do is making sure that your YAML files are uniformly indented (e.g. before being checked into a revision control system). Your idea of dedenting and then re-indenting will not work as you lose information if you flatten your structure. This:

```
foo:
  alice: female
  bob:   male
```

consists of two mappings: a mapping with one key and a value that is mapping of two keys to two values.

This:

```
foo:
alice: female
bob:   male
```

is one mapping with three keys, and key `foo` has as value the null scalar (also writable, apart from the empty string, as `~`, `NULL`, `null` in YAML files).

Most YAML parsers will lose information when reading in a file into internal data:

- comments are dropped
- key ordering is not preserved for mappings
- extra spaces around scalars are not preserved

The [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) Python package (of which I am the author) is an enhancemed parser which to allows round-tripping a YAML file to data and back to YAML to preserve more of the original information. It will preserve comments and key ordering, but it drops e.g. extra spacing around single line scalars.

This round-tripping normally stabilizes on a second round-trip and so this can be used to reindent a YAML file. The `yaml` utility included in the package [`ruamel.yaml.cmd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml.cmd), can be used for that without the need to program things yourself:

```
yaml round-trip your_file.yml --verbose
```

(`round-trip` can be shortened to `rt`) will check whether and how the file would change. It shows a [unified diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format) if it does change. Based on that you can decide to save the file if it stabilizes:

```
yaml round-trip your_file.yml --save
```

the output for `example.yml`:

```
---
foo:
  alice: female  # verified
  bob:   male
bar:
- node:   42
  name: none
-     node: 43
      name: none
```

would be:

```
example.yml:
     stabilzes on second round trip, ok without comments
--- example.yml
+++ round trip YAML
@@ -1,9 +1,9 @@
 ---
 foo:
   alice: female  # verified
-  bob:   male
+  bob: male
 bar:
-- node:   42
+- node: 42
   name: none
--     node: 43
-      name: none
+- node: 43
+  name: none
```

and when saved look like:

```
---
foo:
  alice: female  # verified
  bob: male
bar:
- node: 42
  name: none
- node: 43
  name: none
```

The indentation level is by default 2, but can be set with an option to `yaml`.

Comment: I installed the ramuel.yaml package via `pip` on Ubuntu 16.04LTS but I could not find the `yaml` utility.

Comment: The yaml utility is in the package `ruamel.yaml.cmd`, `ruamel.yaml` only has the library.

Answer (score 2):

I just found another solution, it requires a couple of regular expression replacements.

First choose a single character not included in the yaml. I used "°"

Here I wanted to reindent 4 spaces to 2 spaces:

Search regex "`^((    )*)(    )`" (4 spaces in braces) and replace with "`$1°`" until nothing left to replace.

Replace once all "`°`" with "" (2spaces).. 
Voila!

What happens is that the rightmost indent is sub-sequentially replaced by a placeholder. To avoid incorrect matching of already replaced stuff a placeholder not matching to the search is required.

PS: I know it's not fully automated but most editors have regex replace so it requires no extra installation.

Comment: This strategy worked in Rstudio using `\1°` as the replacement string.